# Calculate this determinant，$a_{ij}=(a^i+x_j^i)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Calculate this determinant:
$$
\left| \begin{matrix}
 a+x_1&  a+x_2&  \cdots&  a+x_n\\
 a^2+x_{1}^{2}&  a^2+x_{2}^{2}&  \cdots&  a^2+x_{n}^{2}\\
 \vdots&  \vdots&  &  \vdots\\
 a^n+x_{1}^{n}&  a^n+x_{2}^{n}&  \cdots&  a^n+x_{n}^{n}\\
\end{matrix} \right|
$$

My work: It can be divided as follows:
$$
V=\left| \begin{matrix}
 x_1&  x_2&  \cdots&  x_n\\
 x_{1}^{2}&  x_{2}^{2}&  \cdots&  x_{n}^{2}\\
 \vdots&  \vdots&  &  \vdots\\
 x_{1}^{n}&  x_{2}^{n}&  \cdots&  x_{n}^{n}\\
\end{matrix} \right|,
$$
$$
D_i=\left| \begin{matrix}
 x_1&  \cdots&  x_{i-1}&  a&  x_{i+1}&  \cdots&  x_n\\
 x_{1}^{2}&  \cdots&  x_{i-1}^{2}&  a^2&  x_{i+1}^{2}&  \cdots&  x_{n}^{2}\\
 \vdots&  &  \vdots&  \vdots&  \vdots&  &  \vdots\\
 x_{1}^{n}&  \cdots&  x_{i-1}^{n}&  a^n&  x_{i+1}^{n}&  \cdots&  x_{n}^{n}\\
\end{matrix} \right|.
$$
Then they  are all Vandermonde determinant.

But the form of result seems to be too complicated, for example
$$
V+\sum{D_i}=\prod_{i=1}^n{x_i}\prod_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant n}{\left( x_j-x_i \right)}+\sum_{i=1}^n{\left( \frac{a}{x_i}\prod_{j=1}^n{x_j} \right) \prod_{\begin{array}{c}
 1\leqslant k<l\leqslant n\\
 k,l\ne i\\
\end{array}}{\left( x_l-x_k \right)}\prod_{p=1}^i{\left( a-x_m \right)}\prod_{q=i+1}^n{\left( x_q-a \right)}}
$$
So how can I get a more concise result?